# Fetching video through file name from video gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone, video, ios-simulator

I have name of some videos which are going to be stored in video gallery of iphone, can I get the url of the video I specify through file name, i.e. if I specify a.png video name then it should return the url of that video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you want to access a video in the user's folders directly.  You can not do this.

Instead you must get the user to select a Video using a standard picker, something like this:

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =
       [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288840/iphone-imagepickercontroller-picking-video-from-photo-library)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my application has to use fixed videos of more then 8 GB memory. Its ipad application and can not use internet. The application need to access video by name. I am not able to find a way to do this functionality as even application's max limit is 2GB. Please help me with the issue

Comment: There isn't a way, you have to get the user to pick the Video to get a reference to it.

Comment: I dont think I understand your question now.  Are you saying you need to download an 8GB video?

Comment: Finally we had fixed videos and application was going to be used by some people only so the solution we found was that client was adding the videos in photo library with fixed name in fixed folder so we could access the video. As application's max limit is 2GB we could neither keep it in application and as internet was not to be used we could not download it, so that was the only solution we found.