# Get video size after Save this video to Photo Library in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

I created Camera using `UIImagePickerController`, after take a video. I clicked on Use Video, I saved this video to Photo library. And now I want to get size of this video. I used `AlAssetLibrary` to save video to Photo library. How can get size of the video has just taken? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    NSURL *recordedVideoURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedVideoURL]) {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedVideoURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){}
         ];
    }

}
```

I tried below code to get size of video but not works:

```
 ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [alasset defaultRepresentation];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:&error];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

Comment: I don't know but when my app is crashed when get size of video by using above code.

Comment: Maybe the video is very big and your app is being killed by memory pressure.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman: Yes,i have done. But i'm stuck in remove overlay image when deselect. Can you show me how to remove overlay when deselect in UICollectionView ? Thks

Comment: That's a topic change, so ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in three ways

1.Use `NSData length`

```
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [alasset defaultRepresentation];
    Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:&error];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
    NSLog(@"Size of video %d",data.length);
```

2.Make use of `ALAssetRepresentationsize`

3.**Worst-Case Scenario:** Use the `videoPathURL` that points to the saved video file, retrieve it again using `ALAsset` and caliculate the size.

Answer (score 1):

1) Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288840/iphone-imagepickercontroller-picking-video-from-photo-library)
question to get your video.

2) After getting your video convert it into `NSData` as refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791049/get-video-nsdata-from-alasset-url-ios).

3)Now use NSData's [length function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIADCAHH) .

It will give to to get the length of your video file.

Comment: Yes, i have read above link, but my app crash when trying to get size of video. Can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this for getting size of video :

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:YOURURL];

CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
```